# Connection to SQL Server from outside

Tags: android, sql-server, security

I need some assistance.

I'm trying to develop an app in Android and my ideia is to the user consult or input information in a database that it's not in the same network. I don't want to open SQL port in the router because it can origin some security problems, also I don't want to use a VPN because it can overload the server (imagine 100 vpns connecting at the same time).
How can I solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to have a server between the client and the database. You can use pretty much any language or library you want, but if you want to use Java or Kotlin I'd suggest checking out Spring Boot, specifically with Spring Data JPA.

The server should, of course, be able to handle many connections at once. You might want to keep a pool of available connections to the database to avoid overloading the database server.